# ng-model in regular ES5 (Angular 2.0)

Tags: angular

I am playing around with *Angular 2.0* and I am having trouble setting up input elements linked to $scope variables like I can in *Angular 1.x*. I can find documentation for typescript but not for *regular ES5*.

In my example below, 'myName' is displayed from the component definition but not linked to the input.

```
function DisplayComponent() {
  this.myName = "Jim";
}

DisplayComponent.annotations = [
  new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
    selector: "display"
  }),
  new angular.ViewAnnotation({
    template:
      '<input [(ng-model)]="myName" type="text">' +
      '<p>name: {{ myName }}</p>'
  })
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  angular.bootstrap(DisplayComponent);
});
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/rra3h6bn/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply have to add `directives : [angular.formDirectives]` to your `ViewAnnotation`, but it fails and I'm not sure why.

Here's your fiddle with [angular2 alpha26](http://jsfiddle.net/d1gon2ng/)

I made it work with alpha35, the last version so far. Which has some changes :

- formDirectives was renamed to FORM_DIRECTIVES
- ComponentAnnotation was renamed to ComponentMetadata
- ViewAnnotation was renamed to ViewMetadata
- The global `angular` is now `ng` (not sure in which version this changed)

Here's the fiddle working with alpha35 : http://jsfiddle.net/ocscbk2u/

You were using a too old version. I recommend you to stick to the last version until a stable one is released.

Comment: Thank you very much... I had a suspicion something was outdated when I tried adding the formDirectives directive initially.